# error in R :invalid subscript type double

Tags: r

When trying this:

```
mutate(total=present$total)
```

I get the error

> invalid subscript type double

Can anyone explain me what that means and why did I get it?

Comment: What is the object that you are referencing?  With no initial object `df %>% mutate...` there is not much known about what's happening.

Comment: present <- present %>%  mutate(total=present$total)

Comment: As i can understand total is an already existing variable and i am trying to create it again using mutate function. But i cannot understand what is exactly happening.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is coming in this piece of code? Can you let us know the output of `mtcars %>% mutate(disp = mtcars$disp)`?

Comment: i am getting the same error..

Comment: mtcars %>% 
+ mutate(disp= mtcars$disp)
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : invalid subscript type 'double'

Comment: Can anyone explain this?